# User records saving to one database but not in other database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Rails and MySql database and Devise for user registration. I have a users table in two databases e.g: db1 and db2. After registering a user, I checked Rails is in the background, user was created there for both databases. When I looked in the users table of db1 there were no records found but records inserted for db2.

Here is my code. Thank you for the help.

```
user model
-----------
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :confirmation_token

after_create :save_to_db2
 def save_to_db2
   @user = User.last
   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("db_second").connection
   sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email) VALUES ('#{@user.username}', '#{@user.email}')"
   connection.execute(sql)  
 end
end

database.yml
-------------
development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
database: db1
pool: 5
username: root
password: root

db_second:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
database: db2
pool: 5
username: root
password: root
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple problems with your approach:

The most important one: By crafting SQL statements this way, you are vulnerable for SQL injection. See [this site](http://rails-sqli.org/) for more information. Please try to avoid building your own SQL and use ActiveRecord's helper methods for this as much as possible.

Secondly, you are talking to the wrong connection. Each request has a database connection. By calling `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("db_second")`, you are changing that one connection to be a connection to "db2". That means after that, all actions will use that connection instead of a connection to "db1".

A possible solution to both problems, is to introduce a second model, with a different connection.

```
class BackupUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.establish_connection
    super(:db_second)
  end

  establish_connection

end
```

Then in your original user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ....

  after_create :make_backup

  def make_backup
    BackupUser.create!(username: username, email: email)
  end

end
```

However, if you are using it for backups, there are probably better tools out there. If a backup is what you want, you might want to look up "hot backup" solutions.